# how to consult the base class of a class

Tags: python

Recently i am learning something about unicode in python2.7, and i want to know something about the base class of str, unicode, basestring, etc. and the relations of them, but i can't find a proper way to look up the base class of them expect read the source code.

e.g.

```
class child(A):
    pass
```

How can i know the base class of child using functions?
The only way is reading the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `child.__bases__`.  A Python class can have multiple base classes.

```
>>> child.__bases__
(<class __main__.A at 0x10052f0b8>,)
```